# How to show "To" field in Outlook 365 as plain text not with the "object" view

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-outlook-365

I need to do operations like copy & past part of the recipients, do text searches and some other stuff with it but with the helpers I cannot, someone knows how can I deactivate that feature?

[image]

Comment: When you copy the object and paste to a field, you can edit in the pasted field. I do this if I need to change the email domain. Objects do not affect Outlook search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the screenshot you provided, I noticed that you want the recipients in the "To" field to be displayed as plain text for copying and other operations on owa. As I know, there seems to be no option to change the display of the "To" field.

If you want to do that before the message is sent, as a workaround, please save this message as a draft after filling in the recipients. And then open the draft and click Forward, the "To" field will be displayed as plain text. (The Forward message can be discarded)

[image]

Comment: Whoao, thats a cool trick, thanks :)